# Sending login and password through PHP Soap Client doesn't get picked up by WCF Service Host?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-authentication

I am instantiating a PHP Soap Client like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8731/MathService?wsdl',array(
'login' => "test2", 'password' => "test"));
```

When I do this above, the Request contains:

`Authorization: Basic dGVzdDI6dGVzdA==`

But the above is not being picked up by my CustomUserNamePasswordValidator.  I just have the WCF Service running in a Console app, so I do not know how to set the client credentials on the service host.  I am using TransportWithCredentialOnly with Basic HTTP and Message="UserName".  My CustomUserNamePassword Validator is hard-coded only to accept test and test as the username and password, but even if I pass in test2 to the SoapClient, the operation still passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Security mode to TransportCredentialOnly and the transport clientCredentialType to Basic and it worked.